# Issue in Export to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, dataset, export-to-excel

I'm developin a web application. I need to export the dataset to excel. The Dataset contains the following text in one column.

**Text in Dataset**

*Employee Benefit Sales – Group Benefit Sales*

When I exported this dataset to excel, all other dataset column values are exported as such in dataset. But this text alone got appended with special character as follows.

**Text exported with Special Character**

*Employee Benefit Sales â€“ Group Benefit Sales*

I don't know how this happens.

Help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Might be encoding problem, might be something else...

Comment: It depends on which method you use to export to Excel, you may check text encoding (UTF/ANSI), "–" character isn't just a "-".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem MIGHT be an encoding problem.

Since we don't know how you're exporting the dataset to excel we can only assume you are creating a file or stream.

You'll need to add a UTF8 BOM to the beginning of file/stream:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()
```

See [this](http://litemedia.info/utf8-encoding-and-excel-csv) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `encoding` if you haven't done so:

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Excel might still fail on this when it tries to read the BOM: http://litemedia.info/utf8-encoding-and-excel-csv